# How do popular apps like WhatsApp and Instagram receive push notifications even while the app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating a native social app which includes features such as Direct Messages, Voice and Video Calls etc and I have been trying to find a way to be able to receive data payloads from Firebase Cloud Messaging containing values such that I create a custom notification based on the type values from the data payload eg for VOIP calls I’d like to set a remoteInput action to see if a person declines or accepts a call or for direct messages add a remoteInput action for a quick reply and so far I haven’t had any luck especially with background services not being allowed anymore ever since the release of Android 8.1. So I would like to know if there’s a workaround I’ve been missing or if it’s even possible and if it is how do these popular apps do it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its same as your mentioned, once after the release of 8.1 apps are now more strict in regarding the background running process. There are actually two insights I had received while developed some projects. 1) More the app is used by the user, the app is sort of whitelisted and can receive more notifications, i.e., the system actually tracks the frequency of app usage. 2) You have the possibility to ignore your app from battery optimization process hence more chance of background process to run.